# Is it possible to clear a specific fill colour of cells within my workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I found questions similar to my question but it didn't solve the exact question I am trying to solve. Other problems were changing fill colour but majority of the time ranges were indicated which likely won't be useful for my code. Essentially what I am doing is I currently run a macro in excel which looks at over a hundred different ranges across my whole workbook. Each range is meant to be either only hard-coded numbers in excel or is meant to consist of only formulas. If a cell is in a range which is supposed to only contain hard-coded numbers is a formula then that cell turns green. If a cell in a range which is supposed to only contain formulas is hard-coded then that cell turns red. The user then looks at these coloured cells and fixes the errors. I am then making a macro to clear these coloured cells to just be white or some other colour. How do I do this? This is very likely a simple question but for some reason I have been unable to figure it out. I only want these specific coloured cells to change fill colour.

Here is the start of my code, it's the very basic outline what I want to achieve

```
Sub Clear_Fill()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Cells.Interior.Color = 50000 Or Cells.Interior.Color = 66000 Then
        Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to iterate over the cells in the sheet one by one and test.  you cannot do this in mass.

Comment: "If a cell is in a range which is supposed to only contain hard-coded numbers is a formula then that cell turns green" -- do you mean you have conditional formatting to change the cell's colour?

Comment: I did not use conditional formatting I made a vba code that did this.

Comment: If you use conditional formatting (`=ISERROR(FORMULATEXT(A1))` or `=NOT(ISERROR(FORMULATEXT(A1)))`) you can just remove the conditions to get rid of the colours

Comment: If you have existing code which applies the colors (it would be helpful to post this), then it might be easier to modify that to also remove any coloring which no longer applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code loop all worksheets in workbook, loop all cells in the worksheet and if criteria met clear color

```
Option Explicit

Sub Clear_Fill()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        With ws
            For Each cell In .UsedRange
                If Cell.Interior.Color = 50000 Or Cell.Interior.Color = 66000 Then
                    Cell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
                End If
            Next cell
        End With

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: @CanadianBeaver glad to hear that this works. If this code satisfy your needed vote it as the correct answer to helps others with the same issue